# Page isn't redirecting properly in reset password functionality in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal, and facing an issue.
When I open one-time link of reset password it shows the Login button, and by clicking on this button, it does not open a page and says "The page isn't redirecting properly". But after 4-5 minutes, the page opens properly by refresh.

Can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Is this issue you are facing in fresh Drupal installation if not then you need to check the loop holes in custom modules that is where all people do shits.

Comment: Yes, it was due to Secure Pages module which was creating the issue. I have added all user pages to secure module.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the duplication in the configuration of `URL redirects`